# Arrays Help Work Shown

Tags: java

```
public class Month {

    static String months[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        months = new String[13];
        months[0] = "null";
        months[1] = "january";
        months[2] = "february";
        months[3] = "march";
        months[4] = "april";
        months[5] = "may";
        months[6] = "june";
        months[7] = "july";
        months[8] = "august";
        months[9] = "september";
        months[10] = "october";
        months[11] = "november";
        months[12] = "december";
        System.out.println("enter number:");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println(a);
    } 
}
```

I have to get userinput for the month number and output the month name. 
Can someone please tell me why I keep getting an error at

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Month.main(Month.java:22)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you post the error? It should tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: The title is very explicit: "work shown". Not "error shown". You want the OP to sell out by posting the error too?

Comment: What is the error?  And how are you running this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For user input, you want to use this :

```
    System.out.println("enter number:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = input.nextInt();
```

Also remember, to add `import java.util.Scanner;` to the top of your file, just below the `package` line

Args are arguments, you have to run them with the program from command line or add it in Run section of your IDE as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You ask the user to enter a number, but don't use it for anything.
You pass the first argument of the main function to the parseInt call, this causes the error you get.